# What is Laravel Forge > Site Details > Meta > Tags?

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-forge

I am using Laravel Forge. When I log into Laravel Forge and select a site, there is a "Meta" menu item at the bottom left.
[image]

At the very bottom, there is a place to enter "Tags".
[image]

I am not sure what this is for. I entered a tag "test" to see if it came up as an SEO meta tag within the HTML header. Nothing returned. There is nothing in the [documentation](https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/introduction.html) that explains its purpose. I believe it has something to do with an Apache setting, but I am not familiar with this.

Comment: It's just for you to identify your servers. Forge is on Nginx, not Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to filter servers and sites so you can search on them:
https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/1055189478585892864

You can manage your tags here
https://forge.laravel.com/user/profile#/tags